# Context switching in M:N threading models?

Tags: operating-systems, threads

I wanted to know how M:N kernel user thread model handles context switching, between multiple khread and pthread. How does the PCB/TCB for process and threads look like, how is state of registers stored while switching between kernel mode and user mode or vise versa, or between kernel threads or between user threads.Any help or reading directions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to research/write a full answer, but this seems like an interesting starting point: http://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.c

Comment: Tanks, all I needed was some direction to proceed with. :)